# Insert % signs in output python

Tags: python

I am beginner of python and trying to insert percentage sign in the output.
Below is the code that I've got.

```
print('accuracy :', accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)*100)
```

when I run this code I got 50.0001 and I would like to have %sign at the end of the number 
so I tried to do as below

```
print('Macro average precision :', precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')*100"%\n")
```

I got error say `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
Can any one help with this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use formatting `'Macro average precision : {:.0%}\n'.format(precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro'))`

Comment: The syntax error is because you simply concatenated a float expression with a character string; this is nonsense in Python.  Vis. `print(50.001"%\n")`.

Answer (score 1):

Use f strings:

```
print(f"Macro average precision : {precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')*100}%\n")
```

Or convert the value to string, and add (*concatenate*) the strings:

```
print('Macro average precision : ' + str(precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')*100) + "%\n")
```

See [the discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180574/string-concatenation-with-vs-f-string_) of the merits of each; basically the first is more convenient; and the second is computationally faster, and perhaps more simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The simple, "low-tech" way is to correct your (lack of) output expression.  Convert the float to a string and concatenate.  To make it easy to follow:

```
pct = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')*100
print('Macro average precision : ' + str(pct) + "%\n")
```

This is inelegant, but easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
print('accuracy: {:.2f}%'.format(100*accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to go about fixing this is by using string concatenation. You can add the percent symbol to your output from your function using a simple + operator. However, the output of your function needs to be cast to a string data type in order to be able to concatenate it with a string. To cast something to a string, use str()

So the correct way to fix your print statement using this explanation would be:

```
print('Macro average precision : ' + str(precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')*100) + "%\n")
```