# Generating continuous default names for new objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a model with a default name field. e.g If its the first object, the default name will be:

`new`, then `new1`, `new2` ...
How do I accomplish this in Django models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
models.CharField(max_length=10, default=generator)

index = 0
def generator():
    # you can define incremental logic or static value.
    global index
    index += 1
    return 'new' + str(index)

# result
# ------
# new1 
# new2
# new3
# new4
# ....
# ....
# ....
```

Comment: I think f strings will be better.

Comment: Would you kindly let me know why? Syntax wise it looks much cleaner. But, performance-wise, is there any benchmark you would like to share?

Comment: `Using the string concatenation operator is slightly faster than using format string literals.` - I found it from this source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180574/string-concatenation-with-vs-f-string

Comment: When using f strings, simply have to write `return f"new{index}"`

Comment: I had no prior idea about the performance honestly. I sort of looked at it after your suggestion. The syntax is definitely cleaner for f strings.

Comment: Anyway, saved the question you shared . Thanks bye use anything since there is no issue of performance.